# Laravel CloudWatch log sequenceToken error

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have deployed my Laravel 5.4 Application on AWS EC2 instance and I am enabled CloudWatch for Logs, referencing the following article.

[PHP application logging with Amazon CloudWatch Logs and Monolog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/php-application-logging-with-amazon-cloudwatch-logs-and-monolog/)

My application using Jobs, So the logs will be created Apache handler and PHP CLI. I am getting the following error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Aws\\CloudWatchLogs\\Exception\\CloudWatchLogsException' with message 'Error executing "PutLogEvents" on "https://logs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://logs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:\n{"__type":"InvalidSequenceTokenException","expectedSequenceToken":"49577640379644408194116745662249836900807896605749479 (truncated...)\n InvalidSequenceTokenException (client): The given sequenceToken is invalid. The next expected sequenceToken is: 49577640379644408194116745662249836900807896605749479602 - {"__type":"InvalidSequenceTokenException","expectedSequenceToken":"49577640379644408194116745662249836900807896605749479602","message":"The given sequenceToken is invalid. The next expected sequenceToken is: 49577640379644408194116745662249836900807896605749479602"}'\n\nGuzzleHttp\\Exception\\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://logs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:\n{"__type":"InvalidSequenceToken in /var/www/html/releases/release_20180104234525/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/WrappedHttpHandler.php on line 192
```

Also, assigned the different group and stream name for CLI and Web, but still am getting the same error.

Comment: Did you restart your queue workers after implementing the CloudWatch integration?

Comment: Yes, We have restarted multiple times. But still, we are getting this issue.